# Depth first search algorithm skipping spaces in maze?

Tags: python, algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

After concluding the first lecture of Harvard's AI course on edX, I have decided to implement the concepts taught, first being the depth-first search algorithm.

The objective of this program is to input a maze in text file `mazefile` and find a path from `S` to `G` using the depth-first search algorithm.

The project currently consists of 4 files, (1) the code with the class methods to operate or use the (2) text file which contains the maze, another text file (3) that contains the result file (where the AI has explored) and the main python script (4). Here they are, feel free to copy and paste these into a folder and to see how they run.

processText.py (file 1)

```
#code to process the mazefile file.

class importMaze:
    def __init__(self,maze):
        self.fileLines = []
        self.fileName = maze
        self.switch = False
        self.toBeReturned = []
    def processThis(self):
        f = open(self.fileName,"r")
        for x in f:
            self.fileLines.append(x[:-1])
        f.close()
        for i in self.fileLines:
            if self.switch == True:
                if str(i) == "END":
                    self.switch = False
                else:
                    self.toBeReturned.append(i)
            else:
                if str(i) == "START":
                    self.switch = True
        return self.toBeReturned
class mazePointer:
    def __init__(self,mazearray):
        self.Sample = mazearray
        self.initialPosition = []
        for y in range(0, len(self.Sample)):
           for x in range(0,len(self.Sample[y])):
               if str(self.Sample[y][x]) == "S":
                    self.initialPosition = [x,y]
        self.currentPosition = self.initialPosition
    def whatIs(self,xcoordinate,ycoordinate):
        return (self.Sample[ycoordinate])[xcoordinate]
    def nearbyFreeSpaces(self,search):
        self.freeSpaces = []
        if self.whatIs(self.currentPosition[0]-1,self.currentPosition[1]) == search:
            self.freeSpaces.append([self.currentPosition[0]-1,self.currentPosition[1]])
        if self.whatIs(self.currentPosition[0]+1,self.currentPosition[1]) == search:
            self.freeSpaces.append([self.currentPosition[0]+1,self.currentPosition[1]])
        if self.whatIs(self.currentPosition[0],self.currentPosition[1]-1) == search:
            self.freeSpaces.append([self.currentPosition[0],self.currentPosition[1]-1])
        if self.whatIs(self.currentPosition[1],self.currentPosition[1]+1) == search:
            self.freeSpaces.append([self.currentPosition[1],self.currentPosition[1]+1])
        return self.freeSpaces

    def moveTo(self,position):
        self.currentPosition = position
```

TestingTrack.py (the main file)

```
from processText import importMaze, mazePointer

testObject = importMaze("mazefile")
environment = testObject.processThis()
finger = mazePointer(environment)
frontier = []
explored = []
result = ""
def Search():
    global  result
    if len(finger.nearbyFreeSpaces("G")) == 1: #If the goal is bordering this space
        result = finger.nearbyFreeSpaces("G")[0]
        explored.append(finger.currentPosition)
    else:
        newPlaces = finger.nearbyFreeSpaces("F") #finds the free spaces bordering
        for i in newPlaces:
            if i in explored: #Skips the ones already visited
                pass
            else:
                frontier.append(i)

while result == "":
    explored.append(finger.currentPosition)
    Search()
    finger.moveTo(frontier[-1])
    frontier.pop(-1)


exploredArray = []
for y in range(len(environment)): #Recreates the maze, fills in 'E' in where the AI has visited.
    holder = ""
    for x in range(len(environment[y])):
        if [x,y] in explored:
            holder+= "E"
        else:
            holder+= str(environment[y][x])
    exploredArray.append(holder)
def createResult(mazeList,title,append): #Creating the file
    file = open("resultfile",append)
    string = title + " \n F - Free \n O - Occupied \n S - Starting point \n G - Goal \n E - Explored/Visited \n (Abdulaziz Albastaki 2020) \n \n (top left coordinate - 0,0) \n "
    for i in exploredArray:
        string+= "\n" + str(i)
    string+= "\n \n Original problem \n"
    for i in environment:
        string+= "\n" +str(i)
    file.write(string)
    file.close()
def tracingPath():
    initialExplored = explored
    proceed = True
    newExplored = []
    for i in explored:
        finger.moveTo() #incomplete
print(explored)
createResult(exploredArray,"DEPTH FIRST SEARCH", "w")
```

mazefile (the program will read this file to get the maze)

```
F - Free
O - Occupied
S - Starting point
G - Goal
(Abdulaziz Albastaki 2020)

START
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OFFFFFFFFFFFFFGO
OFOOOOOOOOOOOOFO
OFOOOOOOOOOOOOFO
OFOOOOOOOOOOOOFO
OFOOOOOOOOOOOOFO
OSFFFFFFFFFFFFFO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
END



Made by Abdulaziz Albastaki in October 2020
You can change the maze and its size however it must
-Respect the key above
-Have ONE Starting point and goal
-The maze must be in between 'START' and 'END'
-The maze MUST be surrounded by occupied space


SAMPLE PROBLEMS:

OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OFFFFFFFFFFFFFGO
OFOOOOOOOOOOOOFO
OFOOOOOOOOOOOOFO
OFOOOOOOOOOOOOFO
OFOOOOOOOOOOOOFO
OSFFFFFFFFFFFFFO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO

OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OFOFFFFFOOOFFFOOO
OFFFOOOFOOFFOOOFO
OFOOOOOFOOFOOOOFO
OSFGFFFFFFFFFFFFO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
```

There is also a resultfile, however if you would just create an empty textfile with that name (no extension), the program will fill it in with results.

The problem is with the resultfile, here it is:

```
DEPTH FIRST SEARCH 
 F - Free 
 O - Occupied 
 S - Starting point 
 G - Goal 
 E - Explored/Visited 
 (Abdulaziz Albastaki 2020) 
 
 (top left coordinate - 0,0) 
 
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OFFFFFFFFFFFFFGO
OFOOOOOOOOOOOOEO
OFOOOOOOOOOOOOEO
OFOOOOOOOOOOOOEO
OEOOOOOOOOOOOOEO
OEFFFEEEEEEEEEEO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
 
 Original problem 

OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OFFFFFFFFFFFFFGO
OFOOOOOOOOOOOOFO
OFOOOOOOOOOOOOFO
OFOOOOOOOOOOOOFO
OFOOOOOOOOOOOOFO
OSFFFFFFFFFFFFFO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
```

The AI skipped a few spaces to get to the goal, why is it doing so?

Feel free to ask me for any clarifications.

Comment: Can you provide the smallest possible version of your code where it produces the wrong result, please? Remove everything that's unimportant for the issue, but still runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are the following issues:

- the last `if` block in `nearbyFreeSpaces` uses a wrong index:

  ```
  if self.whatIs(self.currentPosition[1],self.currentPosition[1]+1) == search:
      self.freeSpaces.append([self.currentPosition[1],self.currentPosition[1]+1])
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  if self.whatIs(self.currentPosition[0],self.currentPosition[1]+1) == search:
      self.freeSpaces.append([self.currentPosition[0],self.currentPosition[1]+1])
  ```
- The final position is not correctly added to the path. The last line of this block:

  ```
  if len(finger.nearbyFreeSpaces("G")) == 1: #If the goal is bordering this space
      result = finger.nearbyFreeSpaces("G")[0]
      explored.append(finger.currentPosition)
  ```

  ...should be:

  ```
      explored.append(result)
  ```